# How would you make this script run faster?

Tags: python, web-scraping, html, performance, processing-efficiency

```
import urllib2
import time

def hunt(url, start="<blockquote>", end="</blockquote>"):
    while 1:
        x = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        y = x.read()
        print y[y.find(start):y.find(end)]
        time.sleep(1)
```

I'm trying to get constant updates of a single element on a web page, including a time interval to avoid getting banned by the server. It doesn't have to be python, btw.

Comment: If the server will only let you run it every so often anyway, how fast does it really need to be?

Comment: I'll try to find out the rate limit of the server, but on the client side I want to do the parsing faster, aswell. I mean fast like wall street fast.

Comment: Does the website have an API? Maybe you can get the value without having to pull the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try an experiment to compare the speed of `str.find()` to `re.search()`:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
import urllib2
import re
start = "<body>"
end = "</body>"
url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
res = req.read()
regex = re.compile('%s.+?%s' % (start, end))
'''

timeit.timeit('''res[res.find(start):res.find(end)]''',
    setup = setup, number = 1000)

timeit.timeit('''res[res.find(start):res.rfind(end)]''',
    setup = setup, number = 1000)

timeit.timeit('''regex.search(res)''',
    setup = setup, number = 1000)
```

With this we get:

0.16357661195633

0.08454644330907968

0.2768974693601649

So it looks like `str.find()` has a pretty decent speed, but if you know your end quote is going to be closer to the end than the beginning you can speed things up with `str.rfind()`.

Another thing you can do is to use multiple threads. Start one thread that constantly fetches URLs and puts them in a Queue, then have another thread process the Queue. This way, when the first thread sleeps while waiting on IO, the second thread will be processing the string from the previous URL. Something roughly along these lines:

```
import Queue
import threading
import urllib2

q = Queue.Queue()
results = []

url = 'http://www.google.com/'
start = '<body>'
end = '</body>'

def get_urls():
    while 1:
        req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        res = req.read()
        print "putting data len", len(res)
        q.put(res)

def process_url():
    url_data = q.get()
    result = url_data[url_data.find(start):url_data.find(end)]
    results.append(result)
    q.task_done()

putter_thread = threading.Thread(target = get_urls)
getter_thread = threading.Thread(target = process_url)

putter_thread.start()
getter_thread.start()
```